# Private vs internal cheaper

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization

I know that `external` is cheaper than `public` due to how arguments are parsed. Is making a function `private` or `internal` cheaper?

Comment: have you tried to monitor the gas in a testnet in both scenarios to check which one is cheaper? I am guessing it is the private function as opposed to internal but it is worth trying.

Answer (score 5):

I have just checked with a small example in JavaScript VM environment of **Remix** using the following contract:

```
contract test {

    function calc(uint256 a, uint256 b) private returns (uint256) {
        return a + b;
    }

    function test(uint256 a, uint256 b) public returns (uint256) {
        return calc(a, b);
    }
}
```

Changing the visibility of `calc` from `private` to `internal` does not change the cost of gas when calling `test`.

However, I have done a 2nd test by putting the two version of `calc` in one contract, i.e. `calc1` as `private` and `calc2` as `internal`.

Then the function defined first in the source code shows a slightly lower gas consumption, however, this is not linked to its visibility. If the first function is `private`, it's cheaper. And if `internal` heads the code, it's vice versa.

So I come to the conclusion that gas cost are the same. This would also be in line with my understanding that the distinction between `private` and `internal` isn't relevant anymore after the code has been compiled.

Answer (score -4):

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=private

internal:
Those functions and state variables can only be accessed internally (i.e. from within the current contract or contracts deriving from it), without using this.
private:
Private functions and state variables are only visible for the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.

Comment: How exactly does that answer the question?????